# Kivymd Datatable Preselect or Autoselect Data on loading not working

Tags: kivy, kivymd

#Hey Guys,

#I want to Preselect or Autoselect few rows upon loading data in MDDatatable as I don't want user #to #select same rows again and again every time they open or use the APP. I tried couple of ways #but #none is working. Any help greatly appreciate!

Tried adding data like below suggested by Google AI Bard
data = [   {"name": "John Doe", "age": 30, "city": "New York", "selected": True}]

Also tried below after adding data..no error but doesnt work on laptop
mddatatable.table_data.data[0]['selected'] = True

```
# Original code rows below by Chatgpt gave error TypeError: 'TableData' object is not subscriptable
#         #mddatatable.table_data[0]['selected'] = True
```